# next-with-apollo, SSR does not work, request is done on client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I have very short code, where I am trying to use https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo , next-with-apolo.
But the SSR does not work in my case, and I am still doing client call, maybe someone can guide me.

My with apollo ->

```
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState }) => {
    return new ApolloClient({
      uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      credentials: "include",
      cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
    });
  },
  {
    render: ({ Page, props }) => {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={props.apollo}>
          <Page {...props} />
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    },
  }
);
```

And the page it self

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import withApollo from "../../HOC/withApollo";
import { getDataFromTree } from "@apollo/react-ssr";

const QUERY = gql`
  {
    me {
      user {
        email
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Profile = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERY);

  console.log(data);

  return <div>{data?.me.user?.email}</div>;
};

export default withApollo(Profile, { getDataFromTree });
```

But the request is still being done in the client.

Comment: You have `useQuery` in your component, what was your expectation? If you want the request to happen on the server we need to move it to `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I am using. It allows to wrap the page(main component) in the HOC and then make request ssr or not ssr.

```
src
│   
│      
│
└───pages
│   │   _app.tsx
│   │   _document.tsx
|   |   index.tsx
│   │
│   |
└───apollo
    │   withApollo.ts
    │   createWithApollo.tsx
```

`createWithApollo.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";

// On the client, we store the Apollo Client in the following variable.
// This prevents the client from reinitializing between page transitions.
let globalApolloClient: any = null;

/**
 * Installs the Apollo Client on NextPageContext
 * or NextAppContext. Useful if you want to use apolloClient
 * inside getStaticProps, getStaticPaths or getServerSideProps
 * @param {NextPageContext | NextAppContext} ctx
 */
export const initOnContext = (ac: any, ctx: any) => {
  const inAppContext = Boolean(ctx.ctx);

  // We consider installing `withApollo({ ssr: true })` on global App level
  // as antipattern since it disables project wide Automatic Static Optimization.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    if (inAppContext) {
      console.warn(
        "Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `withApollo` in `pages/_app`.\n" +
          "Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/opt-out-auto-static-optimization\n"
      );
    }
  }

  // Initialize ApolloClient if not already done
  const apolloClient =
    ctx.apolloClient ||
    initApolloClient(ac, ctx.apolloState || {}, inAppContext ? ctx.ctx : ctx);

  // We send the Apollo Client as a prop to the component to avoid calling initApollo() twice in the server.
  // Otherwise, the component would have to call initApollo() again but this
  // time without the context. Once that happens, the following code will make sure we send
  // the prop as `null` to the browser.
  apolloClient.toJSON = () => null;

  // Add apolloClient to NextPageContext & NextAppContext.
  // This allows us to consume the apolloClient inside our
  // custom `getInitialProps({ apolloClient })`.
  ctx.apolloClient = apolloClient;
  if (inAppContext) {
    ctx.ctx.apolloClient = apolloClient;
  }

  return ctx;
};

/**
 * Always creates a new apollo client on the server
 * Creates or reuses apollo client in the browser.
 * @param  {NormalizedCacheObject} initialState
 * @param  {NextPageContext} ctx
 */
const initApolloClient = (apolloClient: any, initialState: any, ctx: any) => {
  // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
  // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return createApolloClient(apolloClient(ctx), initialState, ctx);
  }

  // Reuse client on the client-side
  if (!globalApolloClient) {
    globalApolloClient = createApolloClient(
      apolloClient(ctx),
      initialState,
      ctx
    );
  }

  return globalApolloClient;
};

/**
 * Creates a withApollo HOC
 * that provides the apolloContext
 * to a next.js Page or AppTree.
 * @param  {Object} withApolloOptions
 * @param  {Boolean} [withApolloOptions.ssr=false]
 * @returns {(PageComponent: ReactNode) => ReactNode}
 */
export const createWithApollo = (ac: any) => {
  return ({ ssr = false } = {}) => (PageComponent: any) => {
    const WithApollo = ({ apolloClient, apolloState, ...pageProps }: any) => {
      let client;
      if (apolloClient) {
        // Happens on: getDataFromTree & next.js ssr
        client = apolloClient;
      } else {
        // Happens on: next.js csr
        client = initApolloClient(ac, apolloState, undefined);
      }

      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <PageComponent {...pageProps} />
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    };

    // Set the correct displayName in development
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
      const displayName =
        PageComponent.displayName || PageComponent.name || "Component";
      WithApollo.displayName = `withApollo(${displayName})`;
    }

    if (ssr || PageComponent.getInitialProps) {
      WithApollo.getInitialProps = async (ctx: any) => {
        const inAppContext = Boolean(ctx.ctx);
        const { apolloClient } = initOnContext(ac, ctx);

        // Run wrapped getInitialProps methods
        let pageProps = {};
        if (PageComponent.getInitialProps) {
          pageProps = await PageComponent.getInitialProps(ctx);
        } else if (inAppContext) {
          pageProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }

        // Only on the server:
        if (typeof window === "undefined") {
          const { AppTree } = ctx;
          // When redirecting, the response is finished.
          // No point in continuing to render
          if (ctx.res && ctx.res.finished) {
            return pageProps;
          }

          // Only if dataFromTree is enabled
          if (ssr && AppTree) {
            try {
              // Import `@apollo/react-ssr` dynamically.
              // We don't want to have this in our client bundle.
              const { getDataFromTree } = await import(
                "@apollo/client/react/ssr"
              );

              // Since AppComponents and PageComponents have different context types
              // we need to modify their props a little.
              let props;
              if (inAppContext) {
                props = { ...pageProps, apolloClient };
              } else {
                props = { pageProps: { ...pageProps, apolloClient } };
              }

              // Take the Next.js AppTree, determine which queries are needed to render,
              // and fetch them. This method can be pretty slow since it renders
              // your entire AppTree once for every query. Check out apollo fragments
              // if you want to reduce the number of rerenders.
              // https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/
              await getDataFromTree(<AppTree {...props} />);
            } catch (error) {
              // Prevent Apollo Client GraphQL errors from crashing SSR.
              // Handle them in components via the data.error prop:
              // https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-error
              console.error("Error while running `getDataFromTree`", error);
            }

            // getDataFromTree does not call componentWillUnmount
            // head side effect therefore need to be cleared manually
            Head.rewind();
          }
        }

        return {
          ...pageProps,
          // Extract query data from the Apollo store
          apolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
          // Provide the client for ssr. As soon as this payload
          // gets JSON.stringified it will remove itself.
          apolloClient: ctx.apolloClient,
        };
      };
    }

    return WithApollo;
  };
};

function createApolloClient(apolloClient: any, initialState: any, ctx: any) {
  // The `ctx` (NextPageContext) will only be present on the server.
  // use it to extract auth headers (ctx.req) or similar.
  apolloClient.ssrMode = Boolean(ctx);
  apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState);

  return apolloClient;
}
```

Worth to mention that here I am using "apollo-upload-client" to be able to upload files, but you can use default link.

`withApollo.ts`

```
import { createWithApollo } from "./createWithApollo";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";

const createClient = (ctx: NextPageContext) =>
    new ApolloClient({

        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        link: createUploadLink({
            uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL as string,
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                cookie:
                    (typeof window === "undefined"
                        ? ctx?.req?.headers.cookie
                        : undefined) || "",
            },
        })
    });

export const withApollo = createWithApollo(createClient);
```

`_app.tsx`

```
   import Router from "next/router";
    import { AppProps } from "next/app";

    
  
    
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
 
    
      return (
          <Component {...pageProps} /> 
      );
    }
    
    export default MyApp;
```

But you need to wrap pages into the HOC withApollo, and you can pass ssr true or leave default false. And if you going execute graphql just as usual all .
You only need to call this inside the page that you render, not in the components you render it in.

`pages/index.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { withApollo } from "../apollo/withApollo";


const Index = () => <div></div>;

export default withApollo({ ssr: true })(Index);
```

Answer (score -1):

The request is being called on client side cause you have written `const { data } = useQuery(QUERY);` in Profile Component. So when component is rendered on client side then that query is called.

If you want to call that query only on server side i.e ssr then use `getServerSideProps` method and in that call the given query and pass the result as props to the Profile Component

Example:

```
const Profile = ({ data }) => {
  // Render data...
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Profile;
```

**Note:** You can import modules in top-level scope for use in getServerSideProps. Imports used in getServerSideProps will not be bundled for the client-side.
This means you can write server-side code directly in getServerSideProps. This includes reading from the filesystem or a database.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for,

Comment: @RomanHrybinchuk Your code is running on server side and client side both. If you want that query should be only run on server side then you have to write that query in getServerSideProps method.

Comment: Yes @SandroMennel , I can attach the solution